# Keras OOM when allocating tensor with shape

Tags: keras, resources, shapes

I have been scratching my head over this OOM Error for days and I am new to Keras. I have tried sampling down my data, lowering batch size, and removing layers from 3D-Unet but nothing is working for me. I am using LIDC IDRI dataset of CT scans of 1010 Patients. After pre-processing I save my volumes of 64x64x64 shape on disk which I extracted from resampled 256x256x256 whole CT scans (That is because at first I was first trying to train on whole CT scans but after getting OOM I decided to go with 64 cubic size shapes). Each patient has 64 shapes of 64x64x64, and in total that makes 64,640 samples on which I have to train my 3D-Unet.

Here’s my Keras code for the model:

```
im_width = 64
im_height = 64
im_depth = 64
path_train = 'D:/LIDC-IDRI-Dataset/'

def npz_volume_generator(inputPath, bs, mode="train", aug=None):
    batch_start_index = 0
    patients = os.listdir(inputPath + "images")
    # loop indefinitely
    while True:
        # initialize our batches of scans and masks
        scan_pixels = []
        mask_pixels = []

        # keep looping until we reach our batch size
        for id_ in range(batch_start_index, batch_start_index+bs):
            # attempt to read the next sample from path
            scan_pixel = np.zeros((im_depth, im_width, im_height))
            scan_pixel = np.load(inputPath + 'images/' + patients[id_])['arr_0']
            mask_pixel = np.zeros((im_depth, im_width, im_height))
            mask_pixel = np.load(inputPath + 'masks/' + patients[id_])['arr_0']

            # check to see if we have reached the end of our samples
            if(batch_start_index >= len(patients)):
                # reset the batch start index to the beginning of our samples
                batch_start_index -= len(patients)
                # if we are evaluating we should now break from our
                # loop to ensure we don't continue to fill up the
                # batch from samples from the beginning
                if mode == "eval":
                    break
            # update our corresponding batch lists
            scan_pixels.append(scan_pixel)
            mask_pixels.append(mask_pixel)

        batch_start_index += bs
        if(batch_start_index >= len(patients)):
            batch_start_index -= len(patients)
        # if the data augmentation object is not None, apply it
        if aug is not None:
            (scan_pixels, mask_pixels) = next(aug.flow(np.array(scan_pixels),np.array(mask_pixels), batch_size=bs))

        #Re-shaping and adding a channel dimension (5D Tensor)
        #batch_size, length, breadth, height, channel [None,im_width,im_height,im_depth,1]
        #yield the batch to the calling function
        yield (np.array(expand_dims(scan_pixels, axis=4)), np.array(expand_dims(mask_pixels, axis=4)))


def conv3d_block(input_tensor, n_filters, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=True):
    # first layer
    x = Conv3D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size, kernel_size), kernel_initializer="he_normal",
               padding="same")(input_tensor)
    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    # second layer
    x = Conv3D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size, kernel_size), kernel_initializer="he_normal",
               padding="same")(x)
    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    return x

def get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.5, batchnorm=True):
    # contracting path
    c1 = conv3d_block(input_img, n_filters=n_filters*1, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)) (c1)
    p1 = Dropout(dropout*0.5)(p1)

    c2 = conv3d_block(p1, n_filters=n_filters*2, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)) (c2)
    p2 = Dropout(dropout)(p2)

    c3 = conv3d_block(p2, n_filters=n_filters*4, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2)) (c3)
    p3 = Dropout(dropout)(p3)

    c4 = conv3d_block(p3, n_filters=n_filters*16, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    # expansive path
    u5 = Conv3DTranspose(n_filters*8, (3, 3, 3), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same') (c4)
    u5 = concatenate([u5, c3])
    u5 = Dropout(dropout)(u5)
    c5 = conv3d_block(u5, n_filters=n_filters*8, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u6 = Conv3DTranspose(n_filters*4, (3, 3, 3), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c2])
    u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
    c6 = conv3d_block(u6, n_filters=n_filters*4, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u7 = Conv3DTranspose(n_filters*2, (3, 3,3), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c1])
    u7 = Dropout(dropout)(u7)
    c7 = conv3d_block(u7, n_filters=n_filters*2, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    outputs = Conv3D(1, (1, 1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c7)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[outputs])
    return model

# initialize the number of epochs to train for and batch size
NUM_EPOCHS = 50
BS = 8

# initialize the total number of training and testing image
NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES = len(os.listdir(path_train+ 'images/'))
NUM_TEST_IMAGES = len(os.listdir(path_train+ 'test/'))

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20, zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize both the training and testing image generators
trainGen = npz_volume_generator(path_train, BS, mode="train", aug=aug)
testGen = npz_volume_generator(path_train, BS, mode="train", aug=None)

# initialize our Keras model and compile it
model = get_unet(Input((im_depth, im_width, im_height, 1)), n_filters=16, dropout=0.05, batchnorm=True)
print(model.summary())
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the network
print("[INFO] training w/ generator...")
H = model.fit_generator(trainGen, steps_per_epoch=NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES // BS,
                        validation_data=testGen, validation_steps=NUM_TEST_IMAGES // BS,
                        epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

There are two issues with the output I get. The first warning I get is this:

```
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\numpy_array_iterator.py:127: UserWarning: NumpyArrayIterator is set to use the data format convention "channels_last" (channels on axis 3), i.e. expected either 1, 3, or 4 channels on axis 3. However, it was passed an array with shape (8, 64, 64, 64) (64 channels). str(self.x.shape[channels_axis]) + ' channels).')
```

It states that the shape passed to Keras library was (8, 64, 64, 64) (64 channels), however the input shape I declared in Input() function of Keras is (64, 64, 64, 1) with 1 being the channel on last axis, you don’t declare batch size here which is 8 in my case, yet Keras state that the shape passed on to it has 64 channels, ignoring the last dimension I gave it.

The second error that I get is as following:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8,32,64,64,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node conv3d_transpose_3/conv3d_transpose}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
     [[{{node loss/mul}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Again I have a problem with shape here, Tensor Shape. My shape should be (8,64,64,64,1) but what it reports is (8,32,64,64,64), not only my number of channels are huge here but I also have no idea where that 32 came from. Is there a different interpretation to Tensor Shape? I think there’s something wrong with my input shapes (which is unknowingly being to set to very large) and that is causing the OOM error.

Comment: Hi @Waqas Ahmed, I a have the same issues, I want to Know how you solved it ?